# Using the built in authentication in Asp.net, an invalid login attempt throws an error in production, but not in debug

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This is the first time I have used the built in individual type authentication.  I am able to register and login successfully.  If I enter in un/pw that does not currently exist when logging in, I get an error page: [image: production error]

however when I'm debugging locally, it works as intended:[image: Debug message]

I'm honestly not sure where any of this stuff is stored in VS to step through the code.  My inkling is that it has something to do with some config files somewhere on the host, Somee, but I have yet to be able to find it.  Google pointed me to the environment variable, but changing that in the launchsettings.json doesn't have any affect.

Comment: It looks like a contributing problem here is the lack of top-level error handling in the application.  Before anybody makes any guesses about the problem, your immediate first step is to find out what the actual error is and what operation is producing that error.  It sounds like the application needs some sort of global error handling to catch errors which were otherwise not caught.

Comment: @David part of my problem is that I created the project with individual account authentication in VS and I don't know where the controls/views reside for the log in page. (I hope that makes sense)

Comment: STEP 1: Figure out the real error message. I am not sure what controls your web host provides, but you need to get it in Developer mode as it says. If you have access to the server machine os, using the browser on the server should be considered developer.

Comment: @cytek04 thanks, I'll start digging around on the web host and see what I can find.  Thank you.

Comment: I just went through and double checked every hit to the database that I created and they are all wrapped in a try/catch.  I didn't build the login from scratch, it was just the built in "Individual Account" thing.  I'd like to put in some error handling there, but I don't see any place to do that.

Comment: Did you try configure the application from development mode to production mode?

Comment: @QiangFu I tried, but I don't know if I'm doing it right.  I set from debug to prod in Visual Studio.

Comment: @TroyMulkey  Add `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` in program.cs and depoly to iis. You would see exception details when reproducing.